# Excel - Save Button

Tags: excel, vba, button, save

I have made invoice system in excel. Where there is a customer name and id which is used as a invoice number. And other details are there as well.
I have added a save Button in excel to save my worksheet with the following vb:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="C:\PDF\Export.pdf", _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Now, it just saves with the 'Export' name. So every time I save it will have the same name.
But I want the save button allow me name the sheet before I save the sheet. Or, is there any way the name of the pdf I save can be according to two cell values in order? Also I want the saved pdf to be opened when this Save button is clicked.

Is it not possible to retrieve the filename from the three different cells in order. J5&J6 for Invoice number, K5&K6 customer name and L8 for status? Is it not possible if the same button will also save certain cell values in another sheet?

Comment: Open a file dialog to ask. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.FileDialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using my folder structure:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim fname As String
    
    fname = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter File Name", Type:=2)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="C:\TestFolder\" & fname & ".pdf", _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Naturally you would change `TestFolder` to `PDF`.

**EDIT#1:**

With cell content like:

[image]

This updated code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim fname As String, s As String
    
    s = " "
    fname = [J5] & [J6] & s & [K5] & s & [K6] & s & [L8]
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="C:\TestFolder\" & fname & ".pdf", _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

will generate a file with the filename `PN123-697 James Ravenswood Shipped` and a filetype of `.pdf`.

Comment: Is it not possible to retrieve the filename from the three different cells in order. J5&J6 for Invoice number, K5&K6 customer name and L8 for status?
Is it not possible if the same button will also save certain cell values in another sheet?

Comment: @w YES it is possible, please update your original question with **1** the addresses of the three cells **2** the contents of the three cells **3** the full filespec of the desired filename/location.

Comment: @Waqar  See my **EDIT#1**